# If Hawking radiation is proved to be true won't black holes lose entropy which is against laws of thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, entropy, hawking-radiation, black-hole-thermodynamics

[Hawking radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation) states that black holes continuously emit radiation. But if its the case won't entropy of black holes decrease which violates the laws of heat, entropy and thermodynamics?

Comment: Quite the contrary, the third law of thermodynamics states that nothing can have a temperature of 0K, which means that black holes have to radiate. That all by itself does, of course, not tell us what the temperature of a black hole would be. It took theoretical calculations by Bekenstein and Hawking, I believe, to tell us what that temperature will be.

Answer (score 9):

Any black body in space radiates and ends up very cold, might even crystallize. The law of increasing  entropy holds for closed systems, in this case   the  whole system:  "all the radiation that left the black body + the black body itself" [microstates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy#Statistical_mechanics).

In the sense that a black hole behaves as a black body the same holds true, it cannot be considered a closed system by itself, the [departing radiation and the microstates generated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation#Black_hole_evaporation) have to be counted in.